# Updating User's sign in Email Address via Microsoft Graph API in C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

Using the Microsoft Graph API in C# I can successfully get a user's details and update say their first name, or details held in extension attributes. However, is it possible to update the email address that they use to sign in with?

I can see this held in the Identities section, but I can't see a way of updating the values held there.

Comment: Have you tried to use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) API call?

Comment: Yes, that's how I've been able to update other parts of the user. There isn't any documentation on how to update the Identities section though.

Comment: I guess you can update only the properties that are present [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body).

Answer (score 4):

> is it possible to update the email address that they use to sign in
> with?

if you refer to [`User.identities` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0) which:

> Represents the identities that can be used to sign in to this user
> account.

then yes it is supported to update this property.

> Note: Updating the identities property requires the
> `User.ManageIdentities.All` permission

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id-or-upn}

{
    "identities": [
        {
            "signInType": "emailAddress",
            "issuer": "{tenant-name}",
            "issuerAssignedId": "{user-signIn-email}"
        }
    ]
}
```

C# example

```
var tenant = "contoso.onmicrosoft.com";
var existingEmailAddress = "current_email@contoso.com";
var newEmailAddress = "new_email@contoso.com";
        
//1 . find user
var users = await graphClient.Users
        .Request()
        .Filter($"identities/any(c:c/issuerAssignedId eq '{existingEmailAddress}' and c/issuer eq '{tenant}')")
        .Select("displayName,id,userPrincipalName")
        .GetAsync();
        
var foundUser = users.FirstOrDefault();
       
//2. update user identity
var user = new User
 {
         Identities = new List<ObjectIdentity>()
         {
             new ObjectIdentity
             {
                 SignInType = "emailAddress",
                 Issuer = tenant,
                 IssuerAssignedId = newEmailAddress    
             }
         }
 };

 await graphClient.Users[foundUser.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(user);
```

Answer (score -1):

**userPrincipalName** is the field that you need to update. As per [Update User Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body) Using body below works for me.

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{USER-ID}
{
  "userPrincipalName": "alias@domain.com"
}
```

Add this field to the C# call and should work.